# Email array doesn't show corresponding text

Tags: php, arrays, email

Please someone tell me, if I have an array like this:

```
$subject = array(); 
    $subject[1] = "legatoria";
    $subject[2] = "restauro";
    $subject[3] = "grafica";
    $subject[4] = "stampa";
    $subject[5] = "amministrazione";
    $subject[6] = "altro";
    $subjectindex = $_REQUEST['subject'];
    if ($subjectindex == 0 || !isset($_REQUEST['subject'])) die ("error message");
    else $subject = $subject[$subjectindex];
```

and the mail sends like this:

```
$mail->Body     .= "message has subject: ".$_POST['subject']."\n";
```

why the subject in the email sent by the user is showed as a number (for example 4) and not as the corresponding text (i.e. stampa) ?

Comment: `$subject[$_POST['subject']]` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['subject']` refers to the exact data returned by an HTML form with `name="subject"`. If your form is sending a number corresponding to the index of `$subject` and you want to print the array value, you need to use:

```
$subject[$_POST['subject']]
```

so:

```
$mail->Body .= "message has subject: ".$subject[$_POST['subject']]."\n";
```

Comment: Also according to provided code `$subject` is already aasigned a value according to `$_REQUEST['subject']`. So `$subject` itself can work too.

Comment: Well, you all sounded convincing with .$subject[$_POST['subject']]. but believe it or not, it doesn't work. I get an "f" as a resulting subject in the message.

Comment: Your code is not setup to change the subject line of the email. The way your code is setup, you are adding the words `message has subject` to the body. If you actually want to populate the subject field, you need to set `$mail->Subject` to whatever you want (in this case `$subject[$_POST['subject']]`). I think your minimal understanding of PHP is making this more difficult than it needs to be. Look somewhere in your code where `f` is being set as the subject and change it.

Comment: there must be a conflict between the subject of the email, that obeys to [$mail->Subject="you got mail from website";] and the fact that I called the array as "Subject". Poor PHP understanding, that's true. Does it work that the word "subject" is always interpreted by default as an email subject?

Comment: my html is <code><label class="solo" for="subject">OGGETTO</label>
   <select class="soloinput" name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value=0> </option>
    <option value=1>legatoria</option>
    <option value=2>restauro</option>
    <option value=3>grafica</option>
    <option value=4>stampa</option>
    <option value=5>amministrazione</option>
    <option value=6>altro</option>
   </select><code>

Comment: Try setting the subject manually, then you can work backwards. Type this code above $mail->Body... `$mail->Subject = 'Test Subject';` and then send the email. See if the subject changes, and if it does, now you change that line of code to whatever you need. If you need more help please go in the stackoverflow PHP chatroom.

Comment: The new subject changes if put after and not before the original subjet, but that's the subject of the email while I need the array's subject to be displayed, i.e. the subject of the message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this post. The right solution was only the one suggested by u_mulder

> "Also according to provided code $subject is already aasigned a value according to $_REQUEST['subject']. So $subject itself can work too"

Thank you